# Any IMDB API to get user's ratings history?

Tags: imdb

I need to be able to import [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/) user's movie ratings into my website. Is there any API for this purpose?

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan it is not a duplicate question. This is about download a list of rating for a particular user. These days is full of Stackoverflow users that doesn't read the question and flag the "possible dublicate tag". It is very boring...it's like each time I enter at the supermarket the owner says I am a thieft and I need to spend time proving I am not!

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is that there is not an API for this purpose (at the moment).

If you need to get a user's movie ratings I think that the best solution for you is to log in at IMDB, go inside the user profile page, click on rating and in the bottom of the page click on the **CSV export**.
This should contains all the data you are looking for and in a good format. The bad news is that you have to follow these steps for each user you want to get the ratings. There is not an automatic procedure to get them.

Comment: As of November 2019, the csv export feature does not seem to exist anymore.

Comment: As of Jan 2021, the CSV export is available under the triple dot menu on the right of the "Your Ratings" text on the right hand side

Comment: @javatarz As far as I understand, your own rating is available, but not other users rating (even if their list is public). This is annoying as it prevent automating the csv downloading even for our own account.

Comment: @Conchylicultor IIRC, IMDB does not allow access to other users' ratings, only aggregated results. Lists might be public but the ratings people gave isn't public information. You can either fetch your own ratings on the aggregated score overall.